# Is there a reason to use library backups if I'm backup up full disks?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

In Windows Backup I can backup libraries or whole drives (or specific folders). I want a *complete* backup of all relevant drives. After selecting the drives, there's still the option to backup libraries:

[image]

Is the backup going to do anything different if I include libraries as well as drives? Should I just backup the whole drive instead? Space used by the backup shouldn't be an issue, since I know the incremental backup is pretty smart..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backing up every drive (partition) on your system and then including libraries as well would largely be redundant.

However, libraries can include files/directories from multiple drives, so depending on your setup, selecting them as well may or may not be redundant. For instance in your example, your Documents Library could contain a directory that resides on D: which is not currently selected in your backup, but this directory on D: would be included due to being in that library.

Furthermore, Libraries can also include Windows shares as well. In practice, I'm not certain if these are included in the Windows Backup however it is entirely possible that they are.

Comment: That's what I figured...does it actually store two backups of the same files then, or is it only logically redundant? I'm aware of all the inter-drive relationships and I know I don't need the libraries backed up beyond what's on the selected drives.

Comment: My guess is logically redundant. You could test this quickly by putting a (large) folder in a library that already is backed up as a part of the drive selection, run the backup, and then compare the size to a previous run.